# Android notifications don't appear, but code runs without errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications

I am working on a large project with a new team, and have been asked to add notifications to be displayed when certain conditions are met, but I am having trouble getting them to display at all.

Here is the code I have right now, with unrelated code omitted:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.context = container.getContext();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.module_menu, container, false);
    this.initNotify("TITLE","Message");
    return view;
}

private void initNotify(String title, String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setFullScreenIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle());

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1, b.build());
}
```

The class it is in is a fragment that was called by my main activity. The code runs when put into new applications with no problems, and displays the notification properly, but refuses to work with this particular project. The minimum API is 8.

Are there any things I may have missed or any snippets that may be preventing me from displaying notifications?

Also, is it possible that the application is "suppressing" notifications from being displayed, and if so what code should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I it is because you are setting notification id as a constant `nm.notify(1, b.build());`. To display all the notifications you must use dynamic values.
like this

```
private void initNotify(String title, String message,int id) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setFullScreenIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle());

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(id, b.build());
}
```

and set notifications as (example)

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
initNotify("title", "message",i);
}
```

Comment: I've tried your method, but the same result happens. The code definitely executes as before with no errors, but nothing is displayed again. Your method does work however on an empty application I used for testing, displaying the notification as intended. This is what makes me think something might be suppressing notifications for whatever reason

Comment: try to add`.setContentIntent`

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately

Comment: @RyanConway change `this.context = container.getContext();` to `this.context = getActivity();`

Comment: Same result. This is really confusing me because all of the suggestions have worked on my other application.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried you code. My machine was OK.

Do you have notification permission?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do I have to explicitly declare a permission for it in my manifest?

Comment: What's your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Target is 9, minimum is 8, and it can't be changed

Comment: Do not use notificationCompat.Builder.

Comment: What should I use instead? Because the developers guide says to use NotificationCompat.Builder to support older devices, and Notification.Builder only goes down to API 11, so I can't use that.

Comment: Notification noti = new Notification(); Try again.'